# Sharing printer over wi-fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer

I have a very simple question that I could not solve.

**Problem at hands:**

> I want to share a printer over wi-fi so that each computer connecting to the network can request to print anything

**Information:**

> - The model of the printer is the Canon MG3200 (supports wi-fi connection)
>
>   - Modem model is HG8247Q
>   - Home network with IP 192.168.1.0/24
>   - IP modem is 192.168.1.1
>   - Printer connects to modem Using WPS successfully
>   - It is possible to print anything from the computer that is directly connected to the modem, but not from any other computer connected to the same network by wi-fi
>   - Devices connected by wi-fi can not even detect the printer

**Question:**

> How can I do to make the printer accessible to all computers on my home network over wifi or cable?

Thanks for all the suggestions!

**Edit:**

Here are two screenshots that show all the available settings that my modem offers when connected through the browser interface. They were separated by "basic settings" and "advanced settings".

- [Basic Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xgPx.png)
- [Advanced Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwksY.png)

Note that I removed the SSID name only while taking the screenshot and it is not blank.

Comment: Did you perhaps enable “AP Isolation” in the router’s WiFi settings?

Comment: AP isolation is my guess, too. It might not be called "Isolation", but something else. Some option that says that devices are not allowed to see each other / talk to each other.

Comment: I tried to access the modem's configuration interface through the browser, but it seems that it has no option that would do something like "isolate" the AP. I've edited the question with two screenshots that show all the settings I can change so you can see for yourself because, as @Slizzered mentioned, it could have another name.

Comment: From what I can see, there is no appropriate option in these screenshots, sorry.

Comment: 1. can you access the printer's web interface, as explained here : https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART166557 ?   2. Can you set a fixed IP for the printer?

Comment: 1. Yes i was able to! 
2. I did change the IP to a fixed one.

Comment: So, you should be able from each PC to go to control panel -> printers -> add printer , and if the PC does not automatically detect the device, insert the printer's IP address. If that works, you're done. uf not, report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. access the printer's web interface, as explained here : support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART166557  (You should be able to access this page from every computer in your network)
2. Set a fixed IP for the printer through the web interface
3. On each PC you want to print from,  install the printer. If the printer is not detected automatically by the installer software, search for it using the fixed IP address. In Windows 7,8,10 this is done through control panel -> printers and devices -> add printer.

Please note: the fixed IP is needed to ensure that the single Computers are always able to find your printer. Normally, even a dynamic IP should work,  but (as I had to find out with other wifi printers) some installation procedures bind the printer port to the IP address, so once the IP changes the computer won't find the printer anymore.

Comment: Doing this solved my problem, and it was super easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First check if the Wifi connected devices don't think the WiFi is public. It should be set to either private or company. If this doesn't fix the issue, you could try to share the printer from the computer that can connect to it.

Assuming you have Windows:
Open Devices and Printers, `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers`, right click on the printer, click Printer Properties and go to the Sharing tab. Tick the box and give the printer a name.

Check if you can find the printer on your network from another computer.

Comment: This will only allow printing while the computer connected to the router is running.

Comment: Yes, I tried this solution, but I can't afford to have the PC turned on all the time for various reasons.
Thanks for the suggestion anyway!